# MVC: Updating a FK Relationship from a SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm playing with MVC4 and EF Code First and I'm having a problem getting a DropDownList to update a foreign key of a model type.

Here are my models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}

public class Party
{
    public int PartyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Host { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

So a Party has a `Host` which is a `Customer`

In the controller for the `/Party/Create` GET method, I'm passing a list of customers in the ViewBag:

`ViewBag.Customers = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "FirstName");`

And then in the View I'm rendering this as a DropDownList:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Host, ViewBag.Customers as SelectList, String.Empty)`

This all works fine, I can choose from a list of customers in the dropdown. However, when I submit the form, the /Party/Create POST method doesn't insert the data because the `ModelState` is not valid. Looking at the `ModelState`, I can see that the `CustomerID` of the chosen Customer is present, but it is failing to be converted from a String to an object of type `Customer`

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the DropDownList to the `CustomerID` property of the `Host`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Host.CustomerID, 
    ViewBag.Customers as SelectList, 
    String.Empty
)
```

Comment: Awesome, that's sorted the problem with the `ModelState` being invalid, thanks! I now have a slightly different issue to look at, namely that it's inserting a new `Customer` instead of just adding a FK relationship to an existing one, even though the ID matches an existing customer. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I've resolved the insertion problem by explicitly adding a `CustomerID` property and decorating it as the foreign key for the `Host` navigation property.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Seems a little annoying that you need to decorate the mode with foreign keys but oh well!